# Firestore addDoc error:Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to save  my data to firestore in React.js app but Firestore returns me Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but

Firebase Config file

```
import { initializeApp,} from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'
import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId:process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
  };

  const app =initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  export const db=getFirestore(app);
  export const auth= getAuth(app)
```

and it is my code for saving data to firebase with addDoc

```
    try{ 
        const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
         const data={
            userId:user.user.uid,
            name: "Pls set name",
            about:"Pls set about",
            profileImg:"",
            contacts:[
                "",
            ]
        }
        const docRef =doc(collection(db,`/users/`));
        await addDoc(docRef,data);
        return user
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }
```

lastly screenshot of error

[image]

Comment: I think if you want to [add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) you should pass a collection reference as the first parameter, try this `addDoc(collection(db,"/users/"), data)`

Comment: I tried like that  `await addDoc(collection(db,"/users/"), data)` now it doesnt return success or fail and also does not save data to firestore

Comment: can you make sure `user` is not empty since you're using it in `data`, also can you try this `await addDoc(collection(db,"users"), data)`

Comment: I tired but it is same

Comment: that's weird, you can try the solution proposed by Doug below

Answer (score 3):

It's customary to use the user's UID as the document ID when creating per-user documents, so that they are easy to find later for that user.  Your code is currently generating two random strings for document IDs, which is definitely not what you want.  The first random ID is coming from your call to `doc()`, then again from your call to `addDoc()`.

To use the UID as the document ID, follow along with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document):

```
await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.user.uid), data);
```

Comment: Thanks I got the point but now it turns me  ` Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')` my data is  `         const data={
            userId:user.uid,
            name: "",
            about:"",
            profileImg:""
        }`

Comment: Something in your data object is undefined.  You'll have to do some debugging to find out what.

Comment: You're using `user.user.uid` in your question, but have `user.user.id` (so without the leading `u` in `uid`) here.